# How can I capture STDOUT on a Python UDF in Snowflake to return as string?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Some Python libraries output the result of their functions to STDOUT - and in a Python UDF in Snowflake I need to capture that value to a String to return it.

For example the output of `help()` or `numpy.show_config()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture stdout using `contextlib.redirect_stdout`.

For example, to capture the output of `help(numpy)`:

```sql
create or replace function help_numpy()
returns string
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
packages = ('numpy')  
handler = 'x'
as $$
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from pydoc import help
import numpy

def x():
    f = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        help(numpy)
    return f.getvalue()
$$;

select help_numpy();
```

Or to capture the output of `numpy.show_config()` you just need to replace the functions called inside the `redirect_stdout()` block:

```py
    with redirect_stdout(f):
       numpy.show_config()
```

Note that to use `help()` we also had to `from pydoc import help`. Otherwise you'll get the error `NameError: name 'help' is not defined in function HELP with handler`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a great idea for all UDF languages. Open source JavaScript is often filled with with `alert`, `window.alert`, `console.log` etc. To capture the alert and console out functions in JavaScript:

```
create or replace function STDOUT()
returns array
language javascript
as
$$
//----- Start of standard out intercepts. Add to top of UDF
console.logs = [];
window = {};
console.log   = function(){ console.logs.push({"type":"log",   "timestamp":new Date().toISOString(), "out":Array.from(arguments)}) };
console.warn  = function(){ console.logs.push({"type":"warn",  "timestamp":new Date().toISOString(), "out":Array.from(arguments)}) };
console.error = function(){ console.logs.push({"type":"error", "timestamp":new Date().toISOString(), "out":Array.from(arguments)}) };
console.debug = function(){ console.logs.push({"type":"debug", "timestamp":new Date().toISOString(), "out":Array.from(arguments)}) };
alert         = function(){ console.logs.push({"type":"alert", "timestamp":new Date().toISOString(), "out":Array.from(arguments)}) };
window.alert  = function(){ console.logs.push({"type":"alert", "timestamp":new Date().toISOString(), "out":Array.from(arguments)}) };
//----- End of standard out intercepts

console.log("My log.");
console.warn("My warning");
console.error("My error");
alert("My alert");
window.alert("My window alert");

return console.logs;

$$;

select STDOUT();
```

Comment: window.alert - nice! (and all the rest too)